# Template of constant global variable

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++

This template definition is OK using MSVC, but can't compile on GNU. What is the problem?
EDIT: I have compiled it with C++11 option (using mingw32)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
const static size_t ALIGN_MASK = 64 / sizeof(T) - 1;    

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    cout << ALIGN_MASK<double>;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you compile with `-std=c++14`?

Comment: [Works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3277f41804038b50).

Comment: I have used mingw32 and -std=C++11 (no C++14 in mingw)

Comment: @Laci `mingw-w64` tracks mainline GCC very closely and therefore does support C++14. I'm not sure what the status of the original `mingw` is, but if it's so far behind as not to support C++14, I'd say you should move away from it.

Comment: "can't compile" is not an acceptable problem description. What is the error?

Comment: thanks, In the meantime I have changed the code, so it works using C++11. I will look for updated GCC compilers. The error message was so unspecific, therefore I omitted it: "prog.cpp:5:21: error: template declaration of 'const size_t ALIGN_MASK'
 const static size_t ALIGN_MASK = 64 / sizeof(T) - 1;    "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variable templates are a C++14 feature. Compile with `-std=c++14` to use this version of the standard.

If that does not work, you will have to upgrade you compiler. If that is not an option, use a `struct` with a `static` member instead.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I made a wrong assumption that if I use the /Qstd=c++11 option on Visual Studio Community 2015, my code will be compatible with any C++11 compiler.